Type narrowing doesn't work in a switch statement
Why does the following code not typecheck (TypeScript 5.5.4):
    type ValidationResult$Type = 'success' | 'invalid_or_expired_token' 
    export type ValidationResult = {
      type: 'success'
      token_info: object
    } | {
      type: 'invalid_or_expired_token'
    };
    
    const x: ValidationResult = undefined as unknown as ValidationResult;
    
    const {type}: {type: ValidationResult$Type} = x;
    
    switch (type) {
        case 'success':
        const {token_info} = x;
        break;
        case 'invalid_or_expired_token':
        break;
    }

while the below, simpler, code does:
// type ValidationResult$Type = 'success' | 'invalid_or_expired_token' 
export type ValidationResult = {
  type: 'success'
  token_info: object
} | {
  type: 'invalid_or_expired_token'
};

const x: ValidationResult = undefined as unknown as ValidationResult;

// const {type}: {type: ValidationResult$Type} = x;
const {type} = x;

switch (type) {
    case 'success':
    const {token_info} = x;
    break;
    case 'invalid_or_expired_token':
    break;
}

Playground

The "type" in the code above is both a keyword - "type" and a variable "type" and a property "type". Consider refactoring your code to use various names in all cases.

@msl you are correct but this has no bearing in this particular case. I tried using eg. "type2" before posting this and had the exact same behaviour

In this demo you can see the two cases together:
A)
function f1() {
  const {type} = x;
  switch (type) { // type is "success" | "invalid_or_expired_token"
      case 'success':
        const test1 = x.token_info; // OK
        break;
      case 'invalid_or_expired_token':
        const test2 = x.token_info; // Error
        break;
  }
}

In this case, type is "success" | "invalid_or_expired_token". When TypeScript is processing the control flow analysis, it is able to see that type comes from x.type, then TS is smart enough to guess that if x.type is "success", then x has the property token_info.
B)
function f2() {
  type ValidationResult$Type = ValidationResult['type'];
  const {type}: {type: ValidationResult$Type} = x;
  switch (type) { // type is "success" | "invalid_or_expired_token"
      case 'success':
        const test1 = x.token_info; // Error
        break;
      case 'invalid_or_expired_token':
        const test2 = x.token_info; // Error
        break;
  }
}

In this case, type is also"success" | "invalid_or_expired_token". When TypeScript is processing the control flow analysis, it is NOT able to see that type comes from x.type. Your annotation {type: ValidationResult$Type} takes precedence over inferring it from x, then TS has no way to connect the dots and guess that if type is "success", then x has the property token_info.
The moral of the story is that you should avoid adding manual type annotation whenever possible.

Thanks. I had suspected that this lack of "connection" (for want of a better word) may have something to do with this but assumed that if the type inferences are the same then that's all that matters. Now it appears that the provenance of the type inferences also matters. I am not fully sold on the "no way to connect the dots" but I am not an expert in compilers. The reason I like manual type annotations sometimes (even when redundant) is because they serve as documentation.

TypeScript could go and connect the dots; it doesn't do it because it tries to optimize for performance. If you are telling the compiler that type is {type: ValidationResult$Type} and x is compatible. Typescript doesn't go further because it requires more computation. It reaches a compromise. If you don't use the type, you are not allowing it to compromise.

I'd recommend including references to the documentation for this feature and the implementing pull request, since that describes how it works.
